# I can upload via USB but not FTDI

Tags: ftdi

I have a Adafruit Pro Trinket. I'm having issues getting GPS and and SD card working together. The trinket can be connected via USB but there is no serial connection do debugging my program is hard.

[image]

I purchased an FTDI connector from sparkfun, installed the FTDI software and connected to the trinket. My code complies but it won't flash. The error is confusing:

Can anyone please help me figure out how to get it to flash?

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Mac OS X), Board: "Pro Trinket 3V/12MHz (FTDI)"

Sketch uses 19,896 bytes (69%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 1,476 bytes of dynamic memory.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem1a21": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Here is the "verbose" version of the error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Mac OS X), Board: "Pro Trinket 3V/12MHz (FTDI)"

Using library SPI in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI 
Using library Adafruit GPS Library in folder: /Users/futurebird/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit-GPS-Library-master 
Using library SoftwareSerial in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial 
Using library SdFat in folder: /Users/futurebird/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat (legacy)

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=12000000L -DARDUINO=10604 -DARDUINO_AVR_PROTRINKET5FTDI -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/eightanaloginputs -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI -I/Users/futurebird/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit-GPS-Library-master -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial -I/Users/futurebird/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp -o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.o 
Using previously compiled file: /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SPI/SPI.cpp.o

(^^repeats many times for different files)

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -Wall -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.elf /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SPI/SPI.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/Adafruit GPS Library/Adafruit_GPS.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/MinimumSerial.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdFatBase.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdFatUtil.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdSpiCard.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdSpiSAM3X.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdSpiSTM32F1.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/SdSpiTeensy3.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FatFile.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FatFileLFN.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FatFilePrint.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FatFileSFN.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FatVolume.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/FmtNumber.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/fstream.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/istream.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/ostream.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/SdFat/utility/StdioStream.cpp.o /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/core.a -L/var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp -lm 
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.elf /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.eep 
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.elf /var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 19,896 bytes (69%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 1,476 bytes of dynamic memory.
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbmodem1a21 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build4892553004123204558.tmp/little_GPS.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/futurebird/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1a21
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem1a21": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

---

### UPDATE

I looked in the /dev/ directory and found these which match the menu in Arduino.

cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
cu.Bluetooth-Modem
cu.JabraREVOa400-SPPDev 
cu.LightBlue-Bean

[image]

The above files are int the dev folder but not cu.usbmodem1a21. How can I get it? Or is it looking for the wrong file?

This is what my board selection looks like. I think the issue is the port?

[image]

Comment: "can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem1a21": No such file or directory"

Comment: I made an update after looking for the file.

Comment: Have you installed the FTDI driver? The error message means avrdude can't find your trinket.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Does the file exist? check with `ls` if the file that avrdude tries to open is actually there
- Do you have the right to open it? Opening a serial port requires having the appropriate rights, iow you user belongs to the same group that the device belongs to.
  On linux this is usually wheel or dialout, depending on the distro. Again, `ls -la` is your friend.
- Is your device identified correctly? Meaning that you are not trying to have avrdude address the device wit the wrong protocol.

Comment: The device is identified as Adafruit pro, 3v FTDI. I can flash successfully with Adafruit pro, 3v USB. The file in question is not there. I don't know how to get it ... or ... I suspect another file since the file is the name at the bottom of the compile window.